# Enabling address bar focus on new tab in firefox

Tags: firefox, about-config

A bit of malware recently overwrote a load of about:config settings in firefox. I've managed to reset them all apart from that when I open a new tab the address bar is no longer focused. Does anyone know which about:config property I should alter to change this

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

1. Start Firefox in [Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode#w_how-to-start-firefox-in-safe-mode). If that helps, an add-on or extension is to blame and you'll probably have to disable them one by one to identify the culprit.
2. Change **browser.newtab.url** from **about:newtab** to **about:blank**, **about:home** or your favourite site.